# Mysql field doesn't display on php text filed

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am having difficulties to display the content of a db field into a php form field. This is part of the php that queries the db:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
            include '../sys/conn.php';
            $risultato = mysqli_query ($conn, "

            SELECT 
                 p.id as ID, 
                 p.post_title, 
                 p.post_excerpt as shortdesc, 
                 p.post_content as longdesc
                 FROM mg_posts as p
                 LEFT JOIN mg_term_relationships as r ON r.object_id=p.id
                 JOIN mg_term_taxonomy as t ON t.term_taxonomy_id=r.term_taxonomy_id
                 JOIN mg_terms as tr ON tr.term_id=t.term_id
                 JOIN mg_postmeta pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
                 WHERE p.ID= 13323
                 GROUP BY p.ID

                 ") or die ("Query non valida: " . mysqli_error($conn));
                 mysqli_close($conn);
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato);
?>

    <body>
        .....

          <div class="col-lg-12">
          <form role="form">

            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Short Desc</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $row['shortdesc']; ?>" >   
            </textarea>
            </div>

           <div class="form-group">
           <label>LongDesc</label>
           <textarea class="form-control" value = "<?php echo $row['longdesc']; ?>" >       
           </textarea>

        </div>
        </div>

        ......
        </body>
        </html>
```

I cannot understand why 'longdesc' in the form displays correctly the content while the 'shortdesc' displays only a white field.

Any idea?

Comment: You tried above query in MySQL and it does have `shortdesc`?? or is it NULL/ empty?

Comment: yes sure -->

select p.id, p.post_excerpt, p.post_content
from mg_posts  p  
where p.id=13323


13323 <strong>Sostanze funzionali:</strong> Glicerina bi... <div class="subt_itemdesc">Cosa rende speciale la ...     <---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for `textarea`, instead of assigning `value`, you should do it like this, because it doesn't really have a `value` attribute. You can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) more on various attributes that `textarea` have:

```
<textarea class="form-control"><?php echo $row['shortdesc']; ?></textarea>
```

The same will apply for your `longdesc` too.